# Java Validation List Openoffice

Tags: java, openoffice.org, openoffice-calc

I'm trying to create a spreadsheet and I want to apply the `ValidationType` "`List`" to a specific cell.

So far I did that:

```
public static void setValidationProperty(XCell cell)
{
    XPropertySet xPropertySet = UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XPropertySet.class, cell);
    XPropertySet xPropSet1 = null;
    XPropertySet xPropSet2 = null;
    xPropSet1 = UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XPropertySet.class, xPropertySet.getPropertyValue("Validation"));
    xPropSet2 = UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XPropertySet.class, xPropSet1);
    xPropSet2.setPropertyValue("Type", ValidationType.LIST);
    xPropSet2.setPropertyValue("ShowList", (short) 1);
    xPropSet2.setPropertyValue("IgnoreBlankCells", (Boolean) true); 
    xPropertySet.setPropertyValue("Validation", xPropSet2); 
}
```

The OpenOffice docs description for type `LIST` is:

*Only strings from a specified list are valid.*

(http://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/sheet/ValidationType.html#LIST)

I was searching the last 3 days but I can't figure out where I have to create this specified list and how to apply it.

If anyone could help me out I would be more then happy.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call method [setFormula1](http://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/sheet/XSheetCondition.html#setFormula1) as shown in Basic at https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=25345.

```
XPropertySet xPropertySet = UnoRuntime.queryInterface(
    XPropertySet.class, cell);
XPropertySet xValidPropSet = UnoRuntime.queryInterface(
    XPropertySet.class, xPropertySet.getPropertyValue("Validation"));
xValidPropSet.setPropertyValue("Type", ValidationType.LIST);
xValidPropSet.setPropertyValue("ShowList", (short) 1);
xValidPropSet.setPropertyValue("IgnoreBlankCells", (Boolean) true); 
XSheetCondition xCondition = (XSheetCondition)
    UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XSheetCondition.class, xValidPropSet);
xCondition.setOperator(ConditionOperator.EQUAL);
xCondition.setFormula1("\"1\";\"2\";\"3\"");
xPropertySet.setPropertyValue("Validation", xValidPropSet);
```

(Caveat: I have not compiled or tested this code).

Also take a look at the [DevGuide page](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/Spreadsheets/Other_Table_Operations#Data_Validation) which shows Java code.

Comment: I already tried the xCondition.setFormula1("\"1\";\"2\";\"3\""); but I used the wrong syntax in there, its working now thanks alot!